# Best practice to prevent sqlite3_php db lock during large data entry?

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm using **sqlite3** with **PHP** for a project. I'm trying to import large data parsing JSON from API & inserting into local sqlite. Here is my code summery-

```
$obj  = json_decode($response);

foreach ($obj as $prt) {

$db = new SQLite3('user.db');
$db->busyTimeout(5000);

$xname=$prt->name;
$xage=$prt->age;
$xsex=$prt->sex;
$xaddress=$prt->address;
$xmobile=$prt->mobile;

$name=SQLite3::escapeString($xname);
$age=SQLite3::escapeString($xage);
$sex=SQLite3::escapeString($xsex);
$address=SQLite3::escapeString($xaddress);
$mobile=SQLite3::escapeString($xmobile);

$insert = "INSERT INTO `customer` (
name,
age,
sex,
address,
mobile

) VALUES (
'$name',
'$age',
'$sex',
'$address',
'$mobile'
)";

$statement = $db->prepare($insert);
$statement->execute();  

$db->close();
unset($db); 

}
```

Code works OK. Problem is it's causing frequent db locks. Import data size is near 2,000 row. If I close the window during the update it also causes db lock. Other functions of the software are also not working during import. What I'm asking is what would be the best practice to import large data without db lock?

Comment: You could try some sort of [transaction control](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-transaction/). See [this post](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) for other database locking resources

Comment: @Jamie_D: Thanks, looking into those.